# I have an HP pavillion 1178 convertible and I was messing with secure boot and now my load HP factory default keys button is greyed out

Tags: boot, secure-boot

What should I do?

I was trying to install mint and it said to disable secure boot, it was greyed out so I cleared the keys and then the load hp factory defaults keys option got grayed out.
[_](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw7iT.jpg)

Comment: The best thing to do for experimenting with operating systems is use a Virtual Machine and forget turning off necessary features.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to clear the current keys? Your screenshot clearly shows Secure Boot being enabled. Just disable it unless you are running Windows 11